# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmat while importing MAT-file in fortran with fintrf.h

Tags: matlab, fortran, gfortran

I try to compile a matlab "fintrf.h" based fortran code with gfortran to import a MAT-file in a fortran program. Here is the compiling commands:

```
gfortran -mcmodel=medium -Ofast  $1.F90 -I/mnt/f/MATLAB/extern/include/ -L/mnt/f/MATLAB/bin/win64/ -cpp -lmat -lmx -Wl,-rpath /mnt/f/MATLAB/bin/win64/ -o $1.exe
```

And I am given these errors:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmat
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmx
```

but I am sure the "libmat.dll" and "libmex.dll" is in "../win64/" dictionary. Can you help me out? Thanks

Comment: Use the `mex` function in MATLAB or in the system shell to build your executable. It will set all the right paths and add all the right libraries for you.

Answer (score 0):

You want `-L` to point to the directory containing the corresponding `.lib` files.

So something like:

```
gfortran ... -L/mnt/f/MATLAB/extern/lib/win64/mingw64 -lmat -lmx ...
```